# Gostaria de saber se esse código está correto. Não tenho certeza de o calculo da "Média após final" está certo

Tags: python, classes

```
class DesempenhoAcademico:

  def __init__(self, aluno, nota1, nota2):
    self.nomeAluno = aluno
    self.nota1 = nota1
    self.nota2 = nota2
    self.situacao = False

  def calcularNotaFinal(self, nota1, nota2):
    self.notaFinal = nota1 + nota2
    return(self.notaFinal)

  def calcularMedia(self, nota1, nota2):
    self.media = (nota1 + nota2) / 2
    if (self.media >= 7.00):
      self.situacao = True
    return (self.media)

  def calcularMediaAposFinal(self, media, notaFinal):
    self.mediaAposFinal = (self.media + notaFinal) / 2
    if (self.mediaAposFinal >= 5.00):
      self.situacao = True
    return(self.mediaAposFinal)  

  def situacaoAluno(self):
    if(self.situacao == True and self.media >= 7.00):
      print("Aluno",self.nomeAluno," está em situação Aprovado por Média")
    elif(self.situacao == True and self.mediaAposFinal >= 5.00):
      print("Aluno",self.nomeAluno,"está em situação Aprovado por Média após Final")
    else:
      print("Aluno",self.nomeAluno,"está em situação Reprovado")


aluno = DesempenhoAcademico("Alexandre Cordel", 10, 8)
print("Aluno 1:")
print("Nome do Aluno:", aluno.nomeAluno)
print("Histórico de Notas:")
print("Nota 1:", aluno.nota1)
print("Nota 2:", aluno.nota2)

minhaNotaFinal = aluno.calcularNotaFinal (10, 8)
print("Nota Final:", minhaNotaFinal)

minhaMedia = aluno.calcularMedia (10, 8)
print("Média Aritmética:", minhaMedia)

minhaMediaAposFinal = aluno.calcularMediaAposFinal (minhaMedia, minhaNotaFinal) 
print("Média Após Final:", minhaMediaAposFinal)

aluno.situacaoAluno()
print("")


aluno = DesempenhoAcademico("Thiago Cavalcante", 3, 3.7)
print("Aluno 2:")
print("Nome do Aluno:", aluno.nomeAluno)
print("Histórico de Notas:")
print("Nota 1:", aluno.nota1)
print("Nota 2:", aluno.nota2)

minhaNotaFinal = aluno.calcularNotaFinal (3, 3.7)
print("Nota Final:", minhaNotaFinal)

minhaMedia = aluno.calcularMedia (3, 3.7)
print("Média Aritmética:", minhaMedia)

minhaMediaAposFinal = aluno.calcularMediaAposFinal (minhaMedia, minhaNotaFinal)
print("Média Após Final:", minhaMediaAposFinal)

aluno.situacaoAluno()
print("")


aluno = DesempenhoAcademico("Raimundo Nunes", 2, 3)
print("Aluno 3:")
print("Nome do Aluno:", aluno.nomeAluno)
print("Histórico de Notas:")
print("Nota 1:", aluno.nota1)
print("Nota 2:", aluno.nota2)

minhaNotaFinal = aluno.calcularNotaFinal (2, 3)
print("Nota Final:", minhaNotaFinal)

minhaMedia = aluno.calcularMedia (2, 3)
print("Média Aritmética:", minhaMedia)

minhaMediaAposFinal = aluno.calcularMediaAposFinal (minhaMedia, minhaNotaFinal)
print("Média Após Final:", minhaMediaAposFinal)

aluno.situacaoAluno()
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu construtor (__init__) você já está dizendo que os parâmetros passados (nome, nota1, nota2) vão ser atribuídos a instância como self.nomeAluno, self.nota1 e self.nota2. Sendo assim, estes valores se tornam acessíveis a todos os métodos da classe através de **self**.

Sendo assim para:

```
def calcularNotaFinal(self, nota1, nota2):
    self.notaFinal = nota1 + nota2
    return(self.notaFinal)
```

Seria suficiente dizer:

```
def calcularNotaFinal(self):
    self.notaFinal = self.nota1 + self.nota2
    return self.notaFinal
```

O mesmo para Calcular Media:

```
def calcularMedia(self):
    self.media = (self.nota1 + self.nota2) / 2
    if (self.media >= 7.00):
      self.situacao = True
    return self.media
```

E o mesmo para média pós final:

```
def calcularMediaAposFinal(self):
    self.mediaAposFinal = (self.media + self.notaFinal) / 2
    if (self.mediaAposFinal >= 5.00):
      self.situacao = True
    return self.mediaAposFinal
```

Como seria o fluxo então intanciando e invocando os métodos ajustados:

```
aluno = DesempenhoAcademico("Alexandre Cordel", 10, 8)

#se o objetivo é apenas imprimir, você pode passar os métodos 
#dentro de uma f-string como abaixo

print(f"Nota Final: {aluno.calcularNotaFinal()}")

print(f"Média Aritmética: {aluno.calcularMedia()}")

print(f"Média Após Final: {aluno.calcularMediaAposFinal()}")

aluno.situacaoAluno()
print("")
```

Comment: Muito obrigada *----*